# Weaker version of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

The Central Limit Theorem applies to i.i.d random variables. I’ve seen mention of a version of the CLT that applies to the sum of random variables that while independent, are *not identically distributed* that claimed that their mean still tends toward a normal distribution, but I can’t find confirmation that this is true, and if so a formal statement and accompanying proof. Is it generally true that the mean of the sequence of partial sums of independent but not identically distributed random variables converges in probability to a standard normal distribution (or something along these lines; I may have some details wrong), and if so can you point me to a reference, ideally with a proof? Or if it’s not true can you explain why not?

Comment: you should look at Lindeberg's condition

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful!

Comment: @bob See section 3.4.2 on page 148 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf for proof.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: These two comments alone or together would form the foundation of a good answer, for the benefit of others finding this question since comments sometimes get deleted.